# Connect to Chromedriver from a different machine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking at a remote test rig using Selenium.

I would like to run chromedriver on a machine, and then send test commands to Selenium via webdriver, from a different machine on the same network.

I did run the chormedriver process with

```
chromedriver --port=9876
```

But when I try to run a script from another machine, on the same network, I get an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.webdriverexception: Message: '192.168.0.7:9876' executable needs to be in path
```

My understanding was that I could point the driver to the location where chromedriver is running, but then I get this error, which I don't really get. What is the point of having chromedriver executable running on port 9876, on the same machine only, if you can't connect to it from another machine on the network?

This is what I do on the other machine to connect to chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('192.168.0.7:9876')
driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Why are you not using Selenium Grid? You can run the hub on your current machine and run a node on the another machine with Chrome instances.

Comment: Good to know; it is my first time using Selenium for this kind of setup; I will check Selenium Grid. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! If you need I can provide a JAVA example as an answer, but I'm not familiar with python :)